# Regex - extract 'user name' part of an email address set inside a sentence

Tags: java, regex

I have a string: `blah1 blah2 username@emailaddress.com.au randomblah`

Words `blah1` and `blah2` won't change. The email address and `randomblah` will change.

I want to extract username using a regular expression (in Java). I've tried a number of things with the closest being

`/blah2 .*(?=(@))/`

This gives me `blah2 username`

I can not work out how to exclude `blah2` from the extract.

Comment: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's in ruby so this may not exactly work in java, but the basic idea is like this.

```
regex = /^.* (?<username>.*)@.*$/
result = regex.match "blah1 blah2 username@emailaddress.com.au randomblah"
puts result[:username] # output is 'username'
```

*note that there is a space between `^.*` and `(?<.`

`^` denotes beginning of a string, `$` denotes the end of a string.

`.*` denotes match any characters before next pattern, which is space in this case.
Note that *matching* here actually means *ignore them*, because we are capturing specific pattern which comes next.

Next to `.*`, there is a space, which serves to mark beginning of specific pattern we want to capture.

And next, we are capturing everything(`.*`) comes *after* a blank space and *before* `@`. We mark this by `()`. And we are naming this as `username` by explicitly writing `username` inside `?<>`.

Then we match everything comes after before the end of line. Note that this also means ignore them.

This is in ruby, so matching and capturing syntax may be different in Java, but hopefully basic idea would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

`.*blah2 (\S*)@.*`

See it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jV3eU4/1)

We are essentially capturing all non-whitespace characters (`\S`) present in between `blah2` and `@`.

The captured username can then be accessed via `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\s+(\w+)@`. This will match all usernames which belong to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Replace `\w` suitably if your username can contain other special characters. You can try this code, it'll extract the username.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class RegexTest{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String data = "blah1 blah2 username@emailaddress.com.au randomblah";
        String regex = "\\s+(\\w+)@";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
        if(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
     }
}
```

Output: **username**

Answer (score 0):

```
regexFindString = Regex("\w*@\w*.\")

    if regexFindString.Matches(String):

            regexFIRST = Regex("blah1 blah2 ")

            regexSECOND = Regex("@\w+")

                x = Regex.Replace(FIRST, "")

                x = Regex.Replace(SECOND, "")
```

My Regex might be rusty, but the idea is:
Take the string and match it with a regex made after symbols like " @ " or "."/".com".
Then create two more regexes with these exact characters ( "blah1 blah2" and "@" or "."/".com" ).
When you got them, just replace them with empty string: "" and give to your username (x) the new value of the string. That is your username.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake number 1 with email address regular expressions is reinventing the wheel poorly and rolling your own regex.

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) has some useful material on this topic including a broad outline of the common pitfalls and useful regex that should cover your needs:

`\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b.`

You can modify it to extract the user name with a regex group by adding a few braces.

`(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+)@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b.`

So use `matcher.find()` to iterate through the matches in your string and `matcher.group(1)` to extract the user name.